# Не устанавливается Puppeteer через Node js

Tags: node.js, npm

Не устанавливается Puppeteer через Node js.
Запускаю *npm i puppeteer*.
Зависает на этом моменте.
[image: Вот что происходит]

Когда нажимаю Ctrl+C, то выдает.
[image: Что выдает при Ctrl+C]

Не понимаю в чем ошибка. Причем другие библиотеки, типа *request* , *express* - устанавливаются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему, установив через *yarn*. Только ждать пришлось очень долго, но она установилась и работает.